# Unable to understand function-pointers in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am reading *The C++ Programming Language* by Bjarne Stroustrup. It states an example to explain function-pointers:

```
int cmp1(const void∗ p, const void∗ q) // Compare name strings
{
  return strcmp(static_cast<const User∗>(p)−>name,static_cast<const User∗>(q)−>name);
}
```

Then it uses this `cmp1` in `ssort`, something like this:

```
int main()
{
  cout << "Heads in alphabetical order:\n";
  ssort(heads,6,sizeof(User),cmp1);
  print_id(heads);
  //Rest of function body                
}
```

My question is: is `&cmp1` being passed as an argument in `ssort()` because we can't pass a function as an argument, we can only pass a function-pointer?

Comment: Yes, `cmp1` is passed as a function pointer to `ssort()`.

Comment: C++11 has closures and lambda expressions. You might prefer them (when possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functions name indeed represent the starting address of the executable code for the function. So it's more like the arrays where its name can be used as pointer to the array itself. Also go through
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: is `&cmp1` being passed as an argument in `ssort()` because we can't pass a function as an argument, we can only pass a function-pointer?

Your code does not use `&cmp1`. Hence, your question does not match your code.

Still, a function can be passed without using the `addressof` operator (`&`).

```
ssort(heads, 6, sizeof(User), &cmp1);
```

is the same as

```
ssort(heads, 6, sizeof(User), cmp1);
```

Functions decay to function pointers in this context.